# How to plot chart of number of users over time

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a chart based on information about user sessions. 
For instance, I have [`this .csv file`](https://pastebin.com/2PdnzFUL) that contains the start and end of a user session. I want to make a chart with time in X axis and number of user in  Y axis, like this image [image].

So, in my example file I would have 3 users (Y axis) from 18:49 to 18:57 (users 3,4 and 5).

I want to do this using pandas, but have no ideia how.

Any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

my friend Breno! You can use Python matplotlib for do that.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = ["0:00", "0:20", "0:40", ...] # time 

y = [0, 50000, 100000, ...] # number of users 1
y2 = [0, 40000, 123000, ...] # number of users 2

plt.figure(1)

plt.plot(x,y, '--', color ='red')
plt.plot(x,y2,'o', color ='green')

plt.show()
```